# Can I develop Windows 10 Modern Apps with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I want to develop a Windows 10 Modern App, but Visual Studio 2015 is super slow on my pc.

My question is, is it possible to use Visual Studio 2012 and in the end publish this app in the Windows Store?

Comment: It will require a time machine. UWP wasn't introduced until 2015, a good 3 years after VS 2012. You *might* be able to use a newer version of the compiler toolset with an older version of the IDE, but I struggle to see the advantage. It will be a giant hassle. The last "fast" version of Visual Studio was either 2008 or 2010. If you can run 2012, 2015 should not be significantly slower.

Comment: Run your VS15 in Administrator mode.on my PC this made it remarkably fast.Cant guarantee though or give a reason why!

Comment: ok thank you i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to develop the UWP apps using the Visual Studio 2012. Please see the **Requirements** in [Develop apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx#Anchor_0).

> Here is the list of software that you need:
>
> - [Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/windows/downloads)
> - [Visual Studio 2015.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526725) Make sure that the Universal Windows App Development Tools are selected from the optional features list. Without these tools, you won't be able to create your universal apps.